# Dapr error initialising state store to local cosmosDB

Tags: docker-compose, azure-cosmosdb, dapr

I am using docker compose to spin up an api, along with Dapr for state management and a local cosmosDB emulator.

When specifying my local azure cosmosDB as the state store in my local Dapr component, the Dapr container fails to start with the error message:
level=warning msg="error initializing state store cosmosdb (state.azure.cosmosdb/v1): Post "https://localhost:8081//dbs": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8081: connect: connection refused"

If I change the Dapr component to point at my cosmosDB in azure the Dapr container works fine, so I know this is an issue with cosmosDB locally. Im new to dapr and cosmos db but I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `https` do you have a self-signed certificate? this might be because of SSL exception.

Also, check if your local Azure Cosmos DB Emulator is running or not by navigating to the below url:

```
https://localhost:8081/_explorer/index.html
```

Checkout some related issues: [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/6788), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-local-emulator), [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/7) try closing and restarting the emulator sometime.